# jQuery scroll effect causing manual scrolling problems

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to create an image viewer using jQuery and have come across a problem that so far I have been unable to fix. The image viewer is very basic, it has one big image on top and 6 small images underneath. When a user clicks on one of the small images the big image src changes to that of the small one. Also, there is a button which when clicked adds a new small image dynamically. All of this works fine as it it.

The problem manifested after I decided to add a scroll effect so that when a new image is generated the page automatically scrolls down so that you can see it. This saves the user from having to do it manually. I have got this to work but it seems to be causing manual scrolling problems on some occasions. By this I mean that sometimes after I add an image and it scrolls down to it, I am unable to manually scroll back up using my mouse wheel.

Sometimes it does respond to the mouse wheel but only after a delay which can last anywhere between 1-20 seconds. When it doesn't respond to the mouse wheel I try the side scroll bar and this works sometimes and other times it is stuck, not allowing me to go up or down. I find that if I add the images 1 by 1, waiting for them to load fully then there generally isn't any problems. But if I keep pressing the add new image button in rapid succession then the problem seems to occur. I also found that if I wait long enough the problem seems to go away which makes me think its due to my scroll effect being so slow and my browser having to wait for it to finish until it lets me manually scroll.

I've thought about disabling the add image button after it is pressed so that the new image can load and the scroll can take place before another new image can be added but I'm hoping there is another solution.

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks

[Link to live demo](http://goo.gl/XjXTWw)

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <button>Add<br>Images</button>

    <div id="large-image-wrap">
        <img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover36.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="small-images-wrap" class="clearfix">
        <div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover36.jpg"></div>
        <div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover64.jpg"></div>
        <div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover44.jpg"></div>
        <div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover45.jpg"></div>
        <div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover31.jpg"></div>
        <div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover65.jpg"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto 20px auto;
position:relative;
}

button{
position:fixed;
margin-left:-105px;
margin-top:19px;
width:100px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
}

#large-image-wrap{
width:960px;
height:320px;
position:fixed;
z-index:10;
}

#large-image-wrap img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
border-top:20px solid white;
border-bottom:13px solid white;
}

#small-images-wrap{
width:960px;
position:relative;
top:353px;
}

.si-box{
width:32%;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin-bottom:1%;
}

.si-box img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

div.si-box:nth-child(2), div.si-box:nth-child(3n+2){
margin:0 2%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var imgNum = 1; 

    // Add new image
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        if(imgNum > 70){imgNum = 1};
        $("#small-images-wrap div:last-of-type").after('<div class="si-box"><img src="http://bilal.cu.cc/images/profile_covers/profile_cover'+ imgNum +'.jpg"></div>');
        imgNum++;

        // Scroll to added image
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#small-images-wrap div:last-of-type").offset().top}, 2000);
    });

    // On click effect
    $(document).on('click', '.si-box img',  function () {
        var $imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#large-image-wrap img").attr("src", $imgSrc);
    });

}); // Document Ready End
```

Comment: Try removing either `html` or `body` out of the animate function.

Comment: @putvande When I remove the html then the scroll effect doesn't work and when I remove the body then the scroll effect works but the problem is still there.

Comment: Wow, you're dealing with a lot of pictures. One way to fix your problems would be to decrease the size of them so it takes less time to load. [Here are some ways to do that](http://thinkmobile.appcelerator.com/blog/bid/140148/Five-Ways-To-Load-Images-Faster-On-Browser). There are other ways as well, it is something you should seriously consider doing first before you try and solve this problem

Comment: Also, have you tried putting the `.animate` line before the `.after` line?

Comment: @Zeaklous I have tried putting the .animate before the .after and this hasn't solved the problem. Also, I am trying to add the images via a css background image as the article you mentioned suggests but I can't get this to work because jQuery seems to be adding extra quotes inside my url() which then goes on to break the inline style statement

Comment: jQuery should only add what it tells you to add... Or you could strip it if it comes with quotes. Have you tried any other methods of making the images smaller?